# Installing Homebrew on Mac

Tags: command-line, homebrew

I am recently trying to install homebrew as an easier way for me to update python (3.8.8) to the newest version (3.10).However every time I try to install homebrew, I get

curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.

How can I fix this?
I have already installed the x-code command lines.

Comment: What OS are you trying to install Homebrew on?

Comment: Currently on Mac OS Monterey (12.0.1)

Comment: @33_Dreams Are you operating behind a firewall or proxy (such as provided by a workplace?)

Comment: I am, currently using my college's internet right now.

Answer (score -3):

Ok, I figured it out. When copy pasting it from the Homebrew site,

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

You have to add -k to it to tell curl to "insecure" the site. Like so.

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL -k https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Comment: While this may solve the problem in your case, it‘s very bad security practice in general.

Comment: What happens if you open https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh in your browser?

Comment: i am facing the same issue. is there any other way of resolving this?